# Is it possible to have different timeline views against the same list?

Tags: 2013, list, view, aggregation

Using a single task list, from our testing it seems that the add to timeline/remove from timeline functions store state across the <del>site</del> list rather than against the view.

Is it possible to select a view and display different timeline state?

Edit:

---

By state I mean that there is that property information for the list (i.e. which tasks should be shown seems to be a list property).

Ideally we wanted tasks shown in an instance of a timeline control to be able to be customised/filtered per instance or determined via a list view.

Comment: what do you mean by timeline state? did you resolve it? because people are voting this question up

Comment: we abandoned this concept as it didn't seem to be feasible with the timeline control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this question [2013 - Where is Timeline task color stored? - SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101477/where-is-timeline-task-color-stored) all the configuration of the timeline is stored in one property of the list.

Therefore it is not possible to use different timeline webparts for one task list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to add multiple time lines. The limitation on SharePoint is that for a task list, there is only one default timeline in which the tasks are added.  We can add another timeline to the list using the list folder properties. If we query the folder properties, we can find the timeline_timeline property which contains the metadata for the graph. We can also find the default timeline name.

The solution is to use JavaScript COM and clone the timeline property. You can also add JavaScript to allow the user to change the default timeline graph or just use the web properties to select the default view.  This way you can have a master timeline as well as secondary timelines.

Find more technical details in this blog.

http://www.ozkary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-2013-adding-multiple.html