# Where is Timeline task color stored?

Tags: 2013, tasks

I've added a few tasks to the timeline and changed their background color using ribbon tab called "Timeline":

[image: timeline background color button]

So now I have something like this:

[image: timeline with custom colors]

The question is where does SharePoint store this color value (e.g. "#FFFF00", or "(255, 255, 0)", so I could use it to something else?

I've tried exploring all Tasks nodes in SharePoint Manager 2013 and searching for this value but I cannot see it anywhere explicitly. Where else can it be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the list's properties: e.g. `web.Lists["Tasks"].RootFolder.Properties["Timeline_Timeline"].Value` (the second word of the property name varies depending on the language) and it's stored as XML data:

```
<TLViewData>
<fmtSet>
    <fmt id="0" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" t1="0" t2="1" type="0" />
    <fmt id="1" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" t1="2" t2="3" type="1" />
    <fmt id="2" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" t1="4" t2="5" type="2" />
    <fmt id="3" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" t1="6" t2="7" type="3" />
    <fmt id="4" clr="FFFF6556" Dclr="FFFF3E2C" Lclr="FFF4948B" thm="0503" t1="6" t2="7" type="3" />
    <fmt id="5" clr="FFFFFF00" Dclr="FFD5D500" Lclr="FFEDED3C" thm="0000" t1="0" t2="1" type="0" />
    <fmt id="6" clr="FF800080" Dclr="FF560056" Lclr="FF9C0E9C" thm="0000" t1="11" t2="12" type="0" />
</fmtSet>
<fltSet>
    <ft id="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" uid="4294967295" uidSrc="1" onTL="0" fmt="1" y="4294967282" x="0" h="20" />
</fltSet>
<tskSet>
    <t id="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" uid="4294967295" uidSrc="1" onTL="0" fmt="0" ch="4294967295" />
    <t id="{8069019F-B7A6-4FC5-9CE3-88E275A7D0F3}" uid="1" uidSrc="1" onTL="1" fmt="5" ch="4294967295" />
    <t id="37b637a4-1587-4353-ae6b-ef75c03362ca" uid="2" uidSrc="1" onTL="1" fmt="6" ch="4294967295" />
</tskSet>
<options dateFormat="255" panZoomT="9" ProjSummFmt="4" showDates="1" showProjSummDates="1" showToday="1" showTS="1" timelineHeight="133" timelineWidth="-1" timescaleT="8" todayT="10" />
<mlSet>
    <m id="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" uid="4294967295" uidSrc="1" onTL="0" fmt="2" y="35" x="0" />
    <m id="{8069019F-B7A6-4FC5-9CE3-88E275A7D0F3}" uid="1" uidSrc="1" onTL="1" fmt="2" y="35" x="0" />
    <m id="37b637a4-1587-4353-ae6b-ef75c03362ca" uid="2" uidSrc="1" onTL="1" fmt="2" y="35" x="0" />
</mlSet>
<txtSet>
    <style id="0" type="0" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="1" type="1" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="2" type="2" clr="FF999999" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="3" type="3" clr="FFB3B3B3" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI Light" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="4" type="4" clr="FF525051" thm="0001" sz="10" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="5" type="5" clr="FFB3B3B3" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI Light" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="6" type="6" clr="FF999999" thm="0001" sz="9" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="7" type="7" clr="FF999999" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="8" type="8" clr="FF999999" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="9" type="9" clr="FFFFA614" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI Semibold" bold="1" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="10" type="10" clr="FFFFA72B" thm="0001" sz="10" font="Segoe UI Semibold" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="11" type="0" clr="FFFFFF00" thm="0000" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
    <style id="12" type="0" clr="FFFFFF00" thm="0000" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" />
</txtSet>
```

where `fmt` is a format and its attribute `clr` is a color stored in ARGB hex format.

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes to the timeline, it does a call back to the list Folder's properties ("Timeline_Timeline"). That's where the values are stored. Using Firebug, open console and check for the callbacks, there should be about 3 callbacks when you make changes to the color. Look into the last callback's JSON or XML data. You'd see the XML that was sent. It would look something like:

```
        <Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName="Javascript Library">
    <Actions>
    <Method Name="SetFieldValue" Id="21" ObjectPathId="18">
    <Parameters>
    <Parameter Type="String">Timeline_Timeline</Parameter>
    <Parameter Type="String"><TLViewData><fmtSet><fmt id="0" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" t1="0" t2="1" type="0" /><fmt id="1" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" t1="2" t2="3" type="1" /><fmt id="2" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" t1="4" t2="5" type="2" /><fmt id="3" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" t1="6" t2="7" type="3" /><fmt id="4" clr="FFFF0000" Dclr="FFD50000" Lclr="FFED3C3C" thm="0000" t1="11" t2="7" type="3" /></fmtSet><fltSet><ft id="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" uid="4294967295" uidSrc="1" onTL="0" fmt="1" y="4294967282" x="0" h="20" /></fltSet><tskSet><t id="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" uid="4294967295" uidSrc="1" onTL="0" fmt="0" ch="4294967295" /></tskSet><options dateFormat="6" panZoomT="9" ProjSummFmt="4" showDates="1" showProjSummDates="1" showToday="1" showTS="1" timelineHeight="110" timelineWidth="1024" timescaleT="8" todayT="10" /><mlSet><m id="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" uid="4294967295" uidSrc="1" onTL="0" fmt="2" y="35" x="0" /></mlSet><txtSet><style id="0" type="0" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="1" type="1" clr="FFEE2222" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="2" type="2" clr="FF999999" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="3" type="3" clr="FFB3B3B3" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI Light" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="4" type="4" clr="FF525051" thm="0001" sz="10" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="5" type="5" clr="FFB3B3B3" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI Light" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="6" type="6" clr="FF999999" thm="0001" sz="9" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="7" type="7" clr="FF999999" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="8" type="8" clr="FF999999" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="9" type="9" clr="FFFFA614" thm="0001" sz="8" font="Segoe UI Semibold" bold="1" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="10" type="10" clr="FFFFA72B" thm="0001" sz="10" font="Segoe UI Semibold" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /><style id="11" type="0" clr="FF4c4b44" thm="0200" sz="9" font="Segoe UI" bold="0" ital="0" und="0" strk="0" /></txtSet></TLViewData></Parameter>
    </Parameters>
    </Method>
    <Method Name="Update" Id="22" ObjectPathId="16"></Method>
    </Actions>
    <ObjectPaths>
    <Property Id="16" ParentId="14" Name="RootFolder"></Property>
    <Property Id="18" ParentId="16" Name="Properties"></Property>
    <Method Id="14" ParentId="4" Name="GetById">
    <Parameters>
    <Parameter Type="Guid">{d3321f18-77a1-4580-ae6f-cc59137dd9e2}</Parameter>
    </Parameters>
    </Method>
    <Property Id="4" ParentId="2" Name="Lists"></Property>
    <Property Id="2" ParentId="0" Name="Web"></Property>
    <StaticProperty Id="0" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current"></StaticProperty>
    </ObjectPaths>
    </Request>
```

Comment: That was helpful but is not actually an answer. My answer includes additional information that are important to finding and interpreting actual data.