# How to create various timeline views of project tasks

Tags: view, task-list, filter

Since it is not possible to relate a timeline to different views of the same task list ([See this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81229/is-it-possible-to-have-different-timeline-views-against-the-same-list)), has anyone found another way to use SharePoint task list and timeline features to show different views of a project timeline?
I tried creating a task list using lookup fields (as [one user in this forum suggested](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116107/tasks-from-multiple-lists-displayed-on-one-timeline-project-summary?rq=1)), but that doesn't work, since you still have to manually add dates to these tasks, otherwise the timeline can't read them.
If I make different task lists for each phase of the project, I can create different timeline for each task list, but then I don't have an overall timeline view.
Has anyone found a solution to display different timeline views of a project while also allowing an overall timeline view of the entire project? Or is SharePoint simply not yet capable of showing multiple timeline views with varying filtered content?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to add multiple time lines. The limitation on SharePoint is that for a task list, there is only one default timeline in which the tasks are added.  We can add another timeline to the list using the list folder properties. If we query the folder properties, we can find the timeline_timeline property which contains the metadata for the graph. We can also find the default timeline name.

The solution is to use JavaScript COM and clone the timeline property. You can also add JavaScript to allow the user to change the default timeline graph or just use the web properties to select the default view.  This way you can have a master timeline as well as secondary timelines.

Find more technical details in this blog entry.

http://www.ozkary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-2013-adding-multiple.html